# SQL queries or object-oriented design?

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, object-oriented-database

I'm working on a large-scale website project. Currently the website is setup so that SQL queries are made to databases to manipulate them (e.g. if you want to add a user to the `user` table you would make an INSERT query).

I'm considering changing the structure to a more object-oriented design. So, there might be a Users class or a Products class. However in this structure, the data would still be stored in a database, so there would be little point in having, for example, a User class (holding each user's individual information). What is the benefit to a object-oriented design like this with a large PHP-MySQL based website?

As you can see, I'm new to structuring large-scale websites. What is the industry-standard for a PHP-MySQL based site? What is the common approach?

Comment: you should consider using a PHP framework such as Laravel, CodeIgniter, etc. that will handle those kind of things for you. Next, the benefit of having a class that reflects your database is for ease of management, and with a class, you can pass that object around your code and you'll know that the object holds values from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kennypu! So would a User object just query the database every time it is asked for information (e.g. `$u->GetName();`)?

Comment: no, that would be inefficient. the way it would work is say you create a new User object using something like `$u = new User($uid)`, the constructor will query the database and grab all the user info, so later in your code you can just do `$u->name`, and it will already have the name, it won't constantly query the database.

Comment: Oh, I see. But in order to save a modification to a field, you would have to do something like `$u->Save();` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are alluding to is called an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM).
I'd suggest Laravel's Eloqent http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent.
But there are many others that dont require frameworks.